# Xampp me indica Acceso Prohibido!

Tags: xampp, windows-server

Tengo una máquina virtual de Windows Server 2008 con un xampp 5.6.3, pero me sale:

Acceso prohibido!
XAMPP nuevo concepto de seguridad:
Acceso a la solicitud objeto sólo está disponible desde la red local.
Este ajuste puede ser configurado en el archivo "httpd-xampp.conf".

Sin embargo, investigue e indican que cambie new Xampp Security y coloque lo siguiente:
Order deny,allow
//Deny from all
Allow from all
ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var

pero a mi no me sale, sólo sale:

// New XAMPP security concept

        Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var

Comment: # New XAMPP security concept
#

     #Require local
     ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var

Luego de modificar el fichero "httpd-xampp.conf" guardamos y reiniciamos el servicio, Y LISTO!!! :D

Comment: ya consegui el error!!